# How to return the last element in a byte array of integers

Tags: arrays, go, slice

In Go, I want to find the last element in an array of integers.

I have a list:

```
    [0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3]
```

I just want:

```
    0.0.3
```

Every time I try to return the last element the console returns

```
    %!(EXTRA uint8=10)
```

Which I assume means I need to convert a byte array to a slice?

Here's my code:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("git", "tag")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
}
fmt.Printf("Variable Type:\n%s\n", reflect.TypeOf(out))
fmt.Printf("Variable:\n%s\n", (out))

slice := out[0: len(out)]
releaseVersion := slice[len(slice) - 1]
fmt.Printf("release version:", releaseVersion)
```

Here's the output:

```
Variable Type:
[]uint8

Variable:
0.0.1
0.0.2
0.0.3

release version:%!(EXTRA uint8=10)
```

Comment: 1. What is "a byte array of integers"? A byte array is of bytes. 2. `0.0.1`, `0.0.2` and `0.0.3` are not integers. 3. You're using slices, not arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see: `%!(EXTRA uint8=10)` is you are calling `Printf` without a format option. You should just call `fmt.Println` instead.

`10` is the encoding of the newline character.

Now, the meat of your question:

You have a byte array (slice).

You are trying to interpret it as lines (strings separated by '\n').

Interpreting a byte array as a string is easy (assuming the bytes do in fact represent a utf-8 string):

```
// assume buf is []byte
var text = string(buf)
```

You want to treat this as a list of strings. Since `git tag` returns lines, you can split by '\n' or you can just call `strings.Fields` which splits by generic whitespace (including newlines); documented here: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields

```
var parts = strings.Fields(text)
```

Now you can easily just get the last element:

```
parts[len(parts)-1]
```

But for safety you should check the list has some elements, otherwise you will crash on out-of-bounds access.

```
cmd := exec.Command("git", "tag")
bufOut, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
}
textOut := string(bufOut)
parts := strings.Fields(textOut)
if len(parts) == 0 {
    log.Fatal("No tags")
}
releaseVersion := parts[len(parts)-1]
fmt.Println("release version:", releaseVersion)
```

> WHY DOES THIS GOT TO BE SO COMPLEX? IN JAVASCRIPT I CAN JUST DO pop()

It's not really that complex. This is just how computers work. When a program runs, it has a standard output which is essentially a byte stream.

I'm guessing javascript does this step for you automatically:

```
textOut := string(bufOut)
parts := strings.Fields(textOut)
```

i.e. converting the program output to a list of strings separated by new lines.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. Just stared go last week so I found it quite frustrating that it has taken me literally hours to figure out how to do something that I've been able to do so simply before. A problem with me, I guess. Not the language.

Comment: No need to be hard on yourself. If there's a problem here it might be lack of patience, although that is understandable if you found yourself using a new language without wanting to do it (forced because of job, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The combined output of the `git tag` command is a list of `tags` separated by a new line. When you execute the `cmd.CombinedOutput()` it returns this value but as a `[]byte`. Now, I believe that what you actually want is a list of strings. So, what you can do is convert the `out` byte array into a string, and then split it by `\n` using the `strings.Split()` function. Then you can access the last `tag` by its index.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
  cmd: = exec.Command("git", "tag")
  out, err: = cmd.CombinedOutput()
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("Variable Type:\n%s\n", reflect.TypeOf(out))
  fmt.Printf("Variable:\n%s\n", (out))

  outString := string(out)
  outStringArray := strings.Split(outString, "\n")
  fmt.Printf("Last tag is: %s", outStringArray[len(outStringArray) - 1])
}
```

You should see `Last tag is: 0.0.3` printed in the console in your example.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Did you log it and get `0.0.3`? I tried this and it returned `outstring is%!(EXTRA string=0.0.1 0.0.2)
 outstring array is %!(EXTRA []string=[0.0.1 0.0.2 ])
 Last tag is:` where the last tag is nothing